# Pandas Cannot Create a DataFrame from a Numpy Array Of Timestamps

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a numpy array of Pandas Timestamps:

```
array([[Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')],
       [Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')],
       [Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')]], dtype=object)
```

I cannot create a DataFrame from this array, as attempting to do so throws the following error:

```
AssertionError: Number of Block dimensions (1) must equal number of axes (2)
```

You can see that the array is clearly 2 dimensional, which i verified by using `ndim`.

Why can't I create a DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `list` comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a =np.array([[pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 15:50:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')],
       [pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 17:10:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')],
       [pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T'),
        pd.Timestamp('2016-05-02 20:25:00+0000', tz='UTC', offset='5T')]], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in a], columns=['a','b','c'])
print (df)
                          a                         b  \
0 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00   
1 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00   
2 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00   

                          c  
0 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00  
1 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00  
2 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00
```

Another solution is [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(a, columns=['a','b','c']))
                          a                         b  \
0 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00   
1 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00   
2 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00   

                          c  
0 2016-05-02 15:50:00+00:00  
1 2016-05-02 17:10:00+00:00  
2 2016-05-02 20:25:00+00:00
```

See [alternate constructors of df](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#alternate-constructors).

Comment: This definitely answers my question, so thank you. I was asking because the original problem I had was that I was attempting to transpose a DataFrame of Timestamps. Even when constructing a DataFrame with `from_records`, transposing throws the same `AssertionError` as before.

For now, I am transposing the numpy array before I construct the DataFrame.